# why is my image not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image object inside a resource file and I'm trying to display it on my web page to no avail. I'm getting the alt text instead.

[image]

Comment: what does the <img> tag look like when you inspect element in browser?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to show code but actually copy the code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use an image in the form of a data url, it is not enough to use the base64 encoded image data in the src attribute, you also need to use a prefix to tell the browser that a data url is following.

Use:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= FlagPic %>" alt="Bla"/>
```

Note that the content type (here image/png) must fit the image graphics format.

Answer (score 4):

Because the src has to start with "data:{image/format};base64,"

Try this:

```
public string FlagPic
{
  get
  {
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
      ClassLibrary1.Resource1.flag.Save(m, ClassLibrary1.Resource1.flag.RawFormat);

      byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();    
      base64Image = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

      return String.Format("data:{1};base64,{0}", base64Image, ClassLibrary1.Resource1.flag.RawFormat);
    }
  }
}
```